# Fluid Flow always starts from Domain Boundary Issue

Tags: modeling, normals, fluid-simulation, cache

Eventhough my inflow is in the center, the fluid flow always starts from the domain boundary. I have ensured that the normals are not inverted and the cache folder is deleted.Usually the first simulation works fine.[image]

The blender file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzhkRkqiPRPtRnVYbFZrSkV2T0U

Comment: I tried your file, it seems to work well here, try to delete your cache manually and retry. if "the first time works" this could mean the cache is created correctly, but after something strange happens...

Comment: Did you bake it multiple times? Also, by delete cache manually, do you mean delete the files in the folder? I did that :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a long outstanding issue:

https://developer.blender.org/T28756

and has been added to the "TODO" list at:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Development/Todo/Tools#Fluid_Simulation

The problem appears to occur when you have a relatively small fluid object compared
to the domain size.

Generally speaking, using an UVSphere as an inflow object isn't a good idea due to the
smaller triangular faces at its "North and South poles".
A less problematic option would be to either use a cube or a level 1 or 2 subsurfed
cube (apply the modifier), if you want to keep the inflow object the same size.

Also, it's good practice to keep all of the fluid simulation elements at a scale of 1
(Your inflow object had a scale of .025, Apply Scale, Ctrl + a > Scale).
(Dimension of 0.05).

Here's your blend file modified using a Subsurfed level 2 cube (subsurf modifier applied)
at the same dimensions (0.05) as the UVSphere inflow object:

[image]

Using an inflow or obstacle object that contains faces with even/equal surface area
doesn't guarantee a successfull fluid simulation result when the voxel size approaches
the size of your fluid object(s). In this case, the only option would be to scale
everything up; which can necessitate tweaking any animation you may have on your fluid
objects.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just started learning Blender and spent an entire day figuring it out. One question: Is there an advantage to use a subsurfed cube vs a normal one?